# Update ActiveAdmin Index page row through AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activeadmin

My index block looks something like this.
Inside notes partial there's some code that fires an AJAX request that updates that user's notes.

```
index do
    column(:name)
    column(:notes) { |transaction| render 'admin/users/notes_field', user: user }
end
```

I want to respond rendering a `admin/users/update.js.erb` template file which inside updates the full user table row, something like this:

```
$("#user_<%= @user.id %>").html("<%= j(render(partial: 'user', locals: { user: @user })) %>");
```

Pretty much rails standard stuff.

How can I accomplish this using ActiveAdmin? I'm not sure how to extract a single row rendering from the index block in order to re-use it in my js.erb template file.

Comment: Hi, you don't need to render js for each row, you need to run ajax for all rows in a page and then update needed DOM elements with ajax's response